# Have they removed the Interval and Timer operators in Rx 3.0?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I can't find the `Interval` operator and the `Timer` operator in Rx 3.0. Have these been removed?

I installed the System.Reactive NuGet package into my console application in Visual Studio 2015 and now I do not see them. Please see the picture below.

[image]

They were present until a week ago when I used the NuGet package manager to get Rx-Main. That got me v2.2.5 of the assembly.

However, now when I search NuGet for Rx-Main, it doesn't turn up in the results. I infer that is due to the announcement on 16th June that Rx was made a part of the .NET foundation and the new NuGet package was called System.Reactive.

Have these been moved?

Comment: Shouldn't the operators be in the static `Observable` namespace, rather than extensions for `IObservable` ?

Comment: My bad. Thank you. They are indeed static methods.

Comment: If you put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Interval` and `Timer` can be found in the static `Observable` namespace. They are not extension methods for `IObservable`.